# Why would "Where 1 <> 1" in a query return all rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I've come across a query in an application that I've inherited that looks like this:

```
Select *
From foo
where
    1 <> 1
```

As I parse that, it should return nothing (`1 <> 1` should evaluate to false, right). However (at least on my Oracle box) it comes back with a full listing of everything in `foo`. When I try the same thing in MSAccess/Jet and MSSQL I get the behaviour I expect.
Why is it different for Oracle (and why would the original developer want to do this)?

Note: I've seen some superstition about the +s and -s of using "where 1 = 1", and it causing full table scans; but I don't think this is what the original developer was intending.

**Small Update:**
In this case `foo` is a view. When I try the same thing on on an actual table, I get what I would expect (no rows).

**Update 2:**
I've following the code further down the rabbit hole and determined that all he's doing is trying to grab the field/column names. I'm still at a loss as to why it's returning the full record set; but only on views.

Literally, he's building the query in a string and passing it on for another function to execute unaltered.

```
'VB6
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strTableName & " WHERE 1 <> 1"
```

In this case strTableName contains the name of a view.

**Update 3:**
For reference, here is one of the views I'm having problems with 
(I've changed the field/table/schema names)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW scott.foo (field1,
                                        field2,
                                        field4,
                                        field5,
                                        field12,
                                        field8,
                                        field6,
                                        field7,
                                        field16,
                                        field11,
                                        field13,
                                        field14,
                                        field15,
                                        field17
                                       )
AS
   SELECT   bar.field1,
            bar.field2,
            DECODE
               (yadda.field9, NULL, 'N',
                DECODE (yadda.field3, NULL, 'Y', 'N')
               ) AS field4,
            bar.field5,
            snafu.field6,
            DECODE
                (snafu.field6,
                 NULL,
                bar.field8,
                   bar.field8
                 - snafu.field6
                ) AS field7,
            DECODE
               (yadda.field10,
                NULL,
            bar.field12,
                yadda.field10
               ) AS field11,
            DECODE
               (SIGN (  yadda.field10 - bar.field12),
                NULL, 'N', 1, 'N', 0, 'N', -1, 'Y'
               ) AS field13,
            bar.field14,
            ADD_MONTHS
               (DECODE (yadda.field10, NULL, bar.field12, yadda.field10
                       ),
                bar.field14 * 12
               ) AS field15,
       FROM clbuttic,
            bar,
            yadda,
            snafu
      WHERE clbuttic.asset_type = bar.asset_type
        AND bar.field16 = yadda.field9(+)
        AND bar.field1 = snafu.field1(+)
        AND (bar.field17 IS NULL)
   ;
```

Appending `Order By 1` (or some column name in the select on foo) seems to convince Oracle to give me back the empty set. It's a long term solution, but not a short term one (changing he code and redeploying is a major PITA). I'm hoping there's a little known setting on the DB side or something wrong in the View that is the cause of this odd behaviour.

Comment: When I run a query like that on Oracle, I get nothing. So I'm not sure what's different for you.

Comment: This query shouldn't return anything in Oracle.

Comment: Same here - "select * from emp where 1 <> 1" returns 0 rows as expected

Comment: After your update, I tried the same on a view, still no rows.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the exact query ?

Comment: Reminds me of the old saying "SELECT isn't broken!"

Comment: Maybe it's interpreting the 1's as floats, and then it may be that 1 <> 1 ...

Comment: maybe a ; after strTableName?

Comment: Can you include the view code? I know that I've seen a bug that caused this behavior in MS SQL Server, but I've never seen it in Oracle.

Comment: Just tried "where cast(1 as integer) <> cast(1 as integer)" with the same result.

Comment: The fact that the query is being built as a string and run dynamically suggests to me that the query being run isn't quite the one you think it is: I would put good money on Oracle NOT being broken here!  Can you get the text of that query and run it in SQL Plus and still get results?

Comment: Yes Tony, I'm 100% sure that is exactly the query I think it is. I've run it in SQLPlus and got exactly the behavior I described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It definitely looks like a bug in the view merging code of the Oracle optimizer. I bet you only get this with views which contain outer joins. Your `ORDER BY` solves it, because it practically forces a `NO_MERGE` on the view.

I wouldn't put either an `ORDER BY` or a `NO_MERGE` hint inside the view though, because (depending on your data volume) it could degrade performance of other queries which use the view. You should put a no_merge hint in the outer query:

```
Select /*+ NO_MERGE(foo) */ *
From foo
where
    1 <> 1
```

You should also raise an SR with Oracle support, as this is definitely a bug. That query should never ever return any rows no matter what you are selecting from, or how complex it is inside. Never ever.

I couldn't reproduce it, so it's probably fixed in the version I'm using. What's the db version you are using?

Comment: I've got 10gR2 (10.2.0.1.0) with patchsets 1 (10.2.0.2.0) and 3 (10.2.0.4.0). I found that the NO_MERGE hint did not solve the problem in any way, and the performance problem not having it in the view right now is worse than what might happen to other queries that depend on them (so I'll go for it).

Comment: However, I agree this has to be a bug. So +1 and cred.

Answer (score 15):

Okay...why this would happen in Oracle is beyond me.  However, I can tell you why it's often used in other DBs: when the person wants the columns returned, but no values.  (Such as for creating a schema for a new table)

Comment: i agree that's a good point...but people should really be using where 1=0 for that purpose IMO.

Comment: @dotjoe ?  Why?  What difference would it make?  One obviously false statement vs. another.

Comment: @beska: to me, just glancing at 1=0 is easier to see false than glancing at 1<>1 or 1!=1. totally a personal preference.

Answer (score 7):

Oracle doesn't do that for me:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Mar 19 13:36:20 2009

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> select * from wrkr where 1 <> 1;

no rows selected

SQL> select count(*) from wrkr;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        88
```

Edit: It's nothing intrinsic with views, either:

```
SQL> create view foo as select * from wrkr;

View created.

SQL> select count(*) from foo;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        88

SQL> select * from foo where 1 <> 1;

no rows selected
```

Comment: You're right. The code I was running was going against a view, not a table. Tables give me the results I expect.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to dynamically generate a `WHERE` clause. This way, you could just append some `OR [another-condition]` clauses and make it work without checking whether the condition is the first one or not.

Comment: But 1 <> 1 is sure to not return any rows, whatever the other conditions are.

Comment: 1 <> 1 OR 1 = 1 will return all rows. Think twice

Comment: It's much more common (I would say better) to use "WHERE 1=1 AND ...".

Comment: @Tony: They satisfy different purposes. The OR thing can be used in constructing OR search queries where at least one of keywords should match. AND one might be used where you want to check existence of all keywords.

Answer (score 3):

### Why use WHERE 1<>1?

The one place I have seen this used, or even used it myself is as a quick way to copy the structure of a table without copying the contents:

```
create table foo2
as select * from foo where 1 <> 1;
```

(except that I always use != rather than <> - which I really shouldn't (see Bill's comment))

### Apparent Oracle Bug

If you have a case where you can clearly demonstrate that Oracle is returning rows in SQL Plus when you execute "select * from my_view where 1<>1" then you should contact Oracle support (or get the authorised person in your company to do so): it would indicate a significant **bug**.  Of course, if you are using an old version of Oracle they will probably just tell you to upgrade!

Comment: FWIW, <> is standard SQL, whereas != is not standard (though it is supported by several database brands).

Comment: That's worth knowing, thanks!  Pity, because != expresses "not equal" far more eloquently IMHO.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought about it before, but I parse != as "not equal" and <> as "inequal". I wonder what I think the difference is? :-)

Comment: I dunno if it's important to prefer <> over !=.  Most programmers are clearly familiar with != from its use in other languages. And I'd guess you will never need to use a database that doesn't support !=.

Comment: That indeed appears to be what the previous programmer was doing.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like bug in the view-merging code in Oracle.  Oracle will take your WHERE clause and merge it into the view SQL, and then come up with a plan for that.

Try your select with this hint and see if the problem goes away:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ ...
```

You could also look at an EXPLAIN PLAN to get some insight into what is going wrong.

Comment: NO_MERGE had no effect on the results (on the view or the select). However playing with explain plan did lead to some curious results. adding 'order by 1' flipped the plan on its head, but adding 'order by "a"' did not (yet still gave me the empty set I wanted).

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound strange, but does the view/table have a column named "1"?

Answer (score 2):

Just brainstorming here, and may be completely wrong, but I want to say I've seen some SQL parsers parse unquoted integers as meaning "column X".   You can confirm this by trying:

SELECT 1
FROM foo
WHERE 1 <> 1

If 1 is full of values from the first column of your table, you probably want to stick to quoted integers:

SELECT * 
FROM FOO
WHERE '1' <> '1'

But, again, I could be completely wrong here.  I don't have an Oracle install handy to try it out on. :p

Comment: I had this thought as well, because I know that you can do this inside the ORDER BY clause, with something like "ORDER BY 1" to order by the first column. I didn't get the same behavior inside a WHERE though, so I really have no idea.

Comment: I get a column called "1" full of about 200,000 rows all consisting of "1".

Comment: Yah know, when I add Order by (any column name / #) I now get an empty set. I can change the code later, but I'm still looking for the why.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE 1 = 1` *should* cause a full table scan, just as omitting the `WHERE` clause entirely.  If you're retrieving every row from the table, of course it's a full table scan.

I can't comment about `WHERE 1 <> 1` failing to work as expected on Oracle.  That sounds really wrong.  Are you certain you saw the result you describe from *that* query?  Try it again to be sure.

Comment: Yup, absolutely sure. I pulled it out and ran it by hand in SQLPLUS and TOAD

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use something like that when you want to only return all of the the columns for the SQL table.  If it isn't working in Oracle, you may want to try something similarly wrong like:

```
Select *
From foo
where
    1 == 2
```

or possibly

```
where
    key < 0
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  But remember that double-equals is not the equality comparison operator in SQL.  You need to use a single-equals in SQL.  Just a matter of trivia FWIW.

Comment: I get the same result when I change the where clause from "1 <> 1" to "1 = 2". It's bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you wanted to simply test a connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very interesting to see the execution plan for the query, using ...

```
explain plan for select ...;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

If you're querying a view then this might show how the predicate is being evaluated in the wrong phase

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT` probably isn't broken.  First, get the exact query string that's causing this behavior.  Run the query directly on the DB, not through the VB 6 app.  Is the problem still occurring?  Go from there.

Comment: I've already tried that through SQLPLUS and through TOAD (Quest Software), with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution

Update the View by appending `order by 1` following the `where` clause.

```
WHERE clbuttic.asset_type = bar.asset_type
    AND bar.field16 = yadda.field9(+)
    AND bar.field1 = snafu.field1(+)
    AND (bar.field17 IS NULL)
order by 1;
```

It treats the symptom (and I don't have to recompile and redeploy the code), but doesn't tell me why I'm getting this strange behavior.

Update:
Doing the order by on a string constant has the same affect, but doesn't alter the plan (as shown by explain plan). An I suspect it will be executed faster that order by 1 (which I think should sort by the first column).

```
WHERE clbuttic.asset_type = bar.asset_type
    AND bar.field16 = yadda.field9(+)
    AND bar.field1 = snafu.field1(+)
    AND (bar.field17 IS NULL)
order by "a";
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to Cody Casterline's thoughts: is column 1 in the view maybe full of NULL values?  If Oracle is interpreting the WHERE as "value in column 1 not equal to value in column 1" and the value in column 1 is NULL, we enter the strange world of SQL NULLs.  It's the case in every SQL dialect I know that NULL=NULL is not true.  Perhaps Oracle decided that NULL<>NULL therefore must be true?

Comment: Nope. The first column happens to be full of data (it is auto numbering). The other columns are on the whole non null as well. If this was the case I would expect my "order by 1" trick not to work.