# Oracle (view table) SQL odd where clause behavior

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I am querying against a third party's Oracle view table from Microsoft Access. The following query:

```
SELECT CUST_NUMBER, TRANS_CODE, CASH_DRWR_DATE
FROM AMSUSER_CUSTHIST_VW
WHERE TRANS_CODE = 'CO'
AND CASH_DRWR_DATE BETWEEN #7/7/14# AND #7/14/14#
```

returns data like:

```
CUST_NUMBER TRANS_CODE CASH_DRWR_DATE
----------- ---------- ----------------------
0000718123  TR                     01-31-2014
0000753077  NL                     06-26-2014
0000738352  NL                     04-02-2014
0000743210  NL                     05-24-2014
...
0000695247  NL                     06-03-2013
...
```

[(Image of more results, some including times)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUBJI.png)

Which doesn't appear to be obeying the `where` clause. Along with expected values, the `TRANS_CODE` includes values other than `CO`, and some of the dates are outside the specified range.

However, the following appears to work:

```
SELECT CUST_NUMBER, TRANS_CODE, CASH_DRWR_DATE
FROM AMSUSER_CUSTHIST_VW
GROUP BY CUST_NUMBER, TRANS_CODE, CASH_DRWR_DATE
HAVING TRANS_CODE = 'CO'
AND CASH_DRWR_DATE BETWEEN #7/7/14# AND #7/14/14#
```

returning

```
CUST_NUMBER TRANS_CODE CASH_DRWR_DATE
----------- ---------- ----------------------
0000718123  CO         07-11-2014 10:02:31 AM
0000695247  CO         07-11-2014 10:13:57 AM
0000729449  CO         07-11-2014 10:10:25 AM
0000695715  CO          07-11-2014 9:45:51 AM 
...
```

[(Image of more results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgmZ5.png)

What's even stranger is that the `CUST_NUMBER` column has the same data for both queries, while the rest of the information differs.

Is there some property of views that could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Why are you posting screenshots of your queries and no just the actual code?

Comment: When you created your question you didn't include the URL's for your screenshots, and as such this question makes absolutely no sense. Please edit the question and post code and results as text instead of screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: OK, good, now you've included the screenshot URLs, but for reasons I'm unable to explain I still can't see them. If you post text instead of screenshots your question will be accessible to more people who might be able to answer it. Thanks.

Comment: Without any further information it looks like a bug. There have been various bugs which could produce this sort of thing ([this is somewhat similar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/663187/266304), for example, but may be something completely different under the hood and could be version-specific). If you get the same results running the queries directly through SQL*Plus to eliminate driver issues, you should probably raise an SR with Oracle. Providing the view definition and Oracle version might point to a known problem, but you'd be better off asking Oracle directly.

Comment: I think your nls_database_parameters for date_format are different than your session, nls_session_parameters.  You should check both. For both the view and query, there is implicit date casting going on with assumptions on these formats.

Comment: @Patrick - agree it would be much better to use explicit conversions, but that wouldn't explain the behaviour here - why the customer `trans_code` filter is being ignored, why the dates are so far outside the range, and why `where` and `having` are behaving so differently.

Comment: Yes, I did not focus on the trans_code. This could be good service request material.